# Laravel Image Quality

Tags: php, image, laravel

Every time I upload a new image to my server, this image is resized. The main issue I'm having is that the image is losing a lot of quality. This is the current code:

```
    $name1 = str_random(10);
    $img = Image::make($img1);
    $img->resize(270,152, function ($constraint) {$constraint->aspectRatio();});
    $img->crop(160, 132, 55, 0);
    $img->save('/imagenes/'.$name1.'.jpg', 100);
    $escena->img1_plx = $name1.'.jpg';
```

I tried with different changes but the image still lose many quality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a new library: Intervention Image

Here is the link: [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction)

You can choose format, dimensions, crop and quality for the images.

Comment: Maybe you are forcing a resize specifing width and height. In this way you can use the aspectRatio constraint.

You can try this:

$img->resize(270,null, function ($constraint) {$constraint->aspectRatio();});

Comment: Any success? I've got no problem at all using that fixed resize.

Comment: It was a good answer, but the main problem was when i reduce too much the image, this lost quality